# My site required permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, mysite

I configured mysite in my environment, everything is ok,
But I need to allow the user to use `newsfeed` only.

- I need to prevent him from adding new site!

I disabled self-site creation and he still can add a new site in his mysite

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove "Create Subsites" permission from users instead.

The [Self-Service Site Creation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-self-service-site-creation) is used to create My sites. Disable the self-site creation will prevent my sites creation.

If your My Sites are hosted by a dedicated web application, you can remove the “Create Subsites” permission from this web application in Central Admin, so that users in this web application cannot create subsites under their my sites.